# Unable to remove white patch (semi circle) in an html page in the header

Tags: html, css, layout, razor

I am working on an Asp.Net MVC application in which I have a layout page in which I see a white patch like a semi circle and I am trying to remove but not successful in doing so.

CSS

```
html {
    background-color: black;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000;
    border-top: solid 10px #000;
    color: #333;
    font-size: .85em;
    font-family: "Segoe UI", Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
}
```

I made my background everything black but I still see a white semi circle patch as in the following image

[image]

May I know a way to fix it.

Comment: Can you show a live version of this? Much easier to debug that way.

Comment: May I know what do you mean by a live version?

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be good. Or the actual site itself if you can't reproduce it on a Fiddle.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on JSFiddle as it is associated with MVC models, a _Layout.cshtml razor view and about the site it is an internal website. so cannot access it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can guess, you are using the default template of a new project. If it is true, the semi-circle you are seeing is coming from the following css:

```
.main-content {
    background: url("../Images/accent.png") no-repeat;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 30px;
}
```

Remove the background from this class and you will get it done. Hope it works.